# HTML why do buttons in forms send data?

Tags: html, forms, button

This is a very rudimentary question, but I am sure someone out there knows why.  In HTML, when I make a button element by itself, and do not give it and `onclick` and no jQuery `.click()` the button will just do nothing.  Perfect.  But when I do this and but the button inside a `<form>` element, it tries to send GET data of all the form elements to the root address of my website?  Why is it doing that?  I didn't make it a submit button or even define a `method` or `action` on that form??

Thanks for the info in advance!

** EDIT **

This is what I did to fix the problem.  For buttons inside the `<form>`, use:

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

And it will not do anything by default.

Comment: I'd like to know this too. Personally I think a button should just be a button, and a `input[type=submit]` element should actually submit the form...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Buttons are mechanism for making things happen. So what is the point of a button that doesn't do anything? And if you don't want any form functionality, why use a `<form`> at all? By the way, `method` is optional and defaults to `GET`; `location` is no attribute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As can be seen at the respective [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/button) entry, the default value for the `type` property of a button element is `submit`. So if you omit it or don't change it to `button` or `reset`, the default behaviour will kick in and the form gets submitted.

```
<form action="">
  <button type="button">Nothing will happen</button>
  <button>Form gets submitted</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I knew it does submit, but not why. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I guess there is not why, probably comes from trying to make it easier to code back in the day... maybe.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind I think the intended use in the early days was just to submit forms. In that days there was no need for an additional `type` property. Later this need came, but to preserve backward compatibility the default type remained `submit`. Just my thoughts - no references on this.

Answer (score 4):

> I didn't make it a submit button

`<button>` elements have [a `type` attribute. The default value is `submit`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-type-BUTTON). Set `type="button"` if you don't want it to submit a form.

> or even define a method

`method` defaults to `GET`

> or location on that form??

`action` defaults to the current URI.

Answer (score 0):

It was designed that way because you sometimes need to know WHICH button was pressed on the server-side. If you want button functionality without a button, use a styled A-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are treated as submit controls in forms, not sure why.

The reason it gets posted to your root is because you didn't specify an `action` and so the default is used.

The reason it used GET is because that's the default `method`.

To prevent it happening, add `return false;` to the end of your button's `onclick`.